# Google big query API returns "too many free query bytes scanned for this project"

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery

I am using Google's big query API to retrieve results from their n-gram dataset. So I send multiple queries of "SELECT ngram from trigram_dataset where ngram == 'natural language processing'".

I'm basically using the same code posted here (https://developers.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart) replaced with my query statement.

On every program run, I have to get a new code of authorization and type it in the console, which gives authorization to my program to send queries to google big query under my project ID. However, after sending 5 queries, it just returns "  "message" : "Exceeded quota: too many free query bytes scanned for this project".

According to Google Big Query policy, their free quota is 100G/month, and I don't think I've even nearly come close to their quota. Someone suggested in the previous thread that I should enable billing information to use their free quota, which I did, but it's still giving me the same error. Is there any way to check the leftover quota or how to resolve this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you've mentioned scans 1.12 GB of data, so you should be able to run it 89 times in a month.

The way the quota works is that you start out with 100 GB of monthly quota -- if you use it up, you don't have to wait an entire month, but you get 3.3 more quota every day.

My guess (please confirm) is that you ran a bunch of queries and used up your 100 GB monthly free quota, then waited a day, and only were able to run a few queries before hitting the quota cap. If this is not the case, please let me know, and provide your project id and I can take a look in the logs.

Also, note that this isn't the most efficient usage of bigquery; an option would be to batch together multiple requests. In this case you could do something like:

```
SELECT ngram 
FROM trigram_dataset 
WHERE ngram IN (
  'natural language processing',
  'some other trigram',
  'three more words')
```