# Google big query API returns “too many free query bytes scanned for this project”

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having the exact same issue as this person here:

[Google big query API returns "too many free query bytes scanned for this project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976137/google-big-query-api-returns-too-many-free-query-bytes-scanned-for-this-project)

But I don't understand how it applies to me. I have a PowerBI Dataflow getting data from bigquery about 8 times a day (it's firebase analytics data, so it quite a lot of data). It was working fine until the start of today. I get the following error message:

> Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free query bytes
>   scanned. For more information, see
>   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

However when I try to find out what Quota I'm exceeding, I really can't seem to find it in the billing section of cloud services. Also, I'm on the Blaze plan, which I thought would just charge me extra when I used more.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!
Jaap

Comment: As an initial check, do you have the GCP project connected to a billing account?

Comment: The issue is that PowerBI uses some default billing project that is usually not the project you are working on. In order to connect using a particular billing project, you need to use this PowerQuery step:

Source = GoogleBigQuery.Database([BillingProject=#"Project Name"]),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't enable billing, the the quota for your project usage will not show up in the console

You need to enable billing, you have a free limit of 100GB to query per month.
With billing enabled you can query more than 100GB of data.

For a complete overview of the free tier quotas see [Free operations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing)